# Region growing algorithm using Saturation layer

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a region growing algorithm using seed point manually chosen to separate a hand from a background. I have to use the Saturation layer.

This is the initial image:

[image]

The saturation layer looks like this:

[image]

And i tried adding a gaussian blur like this:

`GaussianBlur(src, src, Size(5, 5), 2.85, 2.85, BORDER_DEFAULT);`

I tried a lot of variations of the size of the kernel and the X/Y sigma.

After adding the blur the layer looks like this:

[image]

The algorithm that I tried to implement starts from my starting point , checks all the neighbours and based on Average Saturation of the currently region adds the point at the region if the value is close. I tried a lot of variations for the threshold. The code looks like this:

```
while (!q.empty()) {
            Point p = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (isInside(p.y + di[i], p.x + dj[i], H.rows, H.cols)) {
                    if (labels(p.y + di[i], p.x + dj[i]) == 0 &&
                        abs(S.at<int>(p.y + di[i], p.x + dj[i]) - Sat_avg ) < 18) {

                        labels(p.y + di[i], p.x + dj[i]) = k;
                        Sat_avg = (Sat_avg * N + S.at<int>(p.y + di[i], p.x + dj[i])) / (N + 1);
                        q.emplace(p.x + dj[i], p.y + di[i]);
                        N++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any advice what can I change to the algorithm so I can only get the hand with small loss that I can adapt with dilation and erosion?
Some results based on the starting point:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: saturation layer? why? tell us the name of the person who makes you use the saturation layer. that's got no features delineating the skin from the background

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz "Implement region growing algorithm for H and S components (HSV) (separately and combined) with manually chosen seed point (mouse click). Comparative analysis and conclusions. " This is my assignment at university.. I managed to do it for the H layer but im stuck on the saturation layer for days...

Comment: I think that *might* be the point the instructor is trying to make.